# Black gap at the top of HTML5 video?

Tags: html, video

I've got this bizarre black gap at the top of a HTML5 video I'm running. CSS/HTML/JS is on this fiddle page: https://jsfiddle.net/w6wfdeco/2/

HTML:

```
<!-- Video test -->

<div id="video_overlays">

<div class="abovethefold">
    <h1 class="blog-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
    <?php $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' ); ?>
    <?php if($description) { ?><p class="blog-description"><?php echo $description ?></p><?php } ?>

        <p class="button">
<a class="blue-button" href="#cta">Call to Action</a></p>
</div></div>

</div>


<div class="homepage-hero-module">
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="filter"></div>
    <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
        <source src="http://scott.ewarena.com/blog/wp-content/themes/bootstrapstarter/Busy-People/MP4/Busy-People.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
        <source src="http://scott.ewarena.com/blog/wp-content/themes/bootstrapstarter/Busy-People/WEBM/Busy-People.webm" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
        <img src="http://scott.ewarena.com/blog/wp-content/themes/bootstrapstarter/Busy-People/Snapshot/Busy-People.jpg" title="Your browser does not support the <video> tag">
                                <div class="poster hidden">
        <img src="http://scott.ewarena.com//blog/wp-content/themes/bootstrapstarter/Busy-People/Snapshots/Busy-People.jpg" alt="">

        </video>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.homepage-hero-module {
border-right: none;
border-left: none;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
}
.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
display: none;
}
.no-video .video-container .poster,
.touch .video-container .poster {
display: block !important;
}
.video-container {
position: relative;
bottom: 0%;
left: 0%;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background: #000;
}
.video-container .poster img {
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
}
.video-container .filter {
/*z-index: 100;*/
position: absolute;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
width: 100%;
}
.video-container video {
position: absolute;
/*z-index: 0;*/
bottom: 0;
}
.video-container video.fillWidth {
width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
//jQuery is required to run this code
$( document ).ready(function() {

scaleVideoContainer();

initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
initBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    scaleVideoContainer();
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
    scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
});

});

function scaleVideoContainer() {

var height = $(window).height() + 5;
var unitHeight = parseInt(height) + 'px';
$('.homepage-hero-module').css('height',unitHeight);

}

function initBannerVideoSize(element){

$(element).each(function(){
    $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
    $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
});

scaleBannerVideoSize(element);

}

function scaleBannerVideoSize(element){

var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
windowHeight = $(window).height() + 5,
videoWidth,
videoHeight;

console.log(windowHeight);

$(element).each(function(){
    var videoAspectRatio = $(this).data('height')/$(this).data('width');

    $(this).width(windowWidth);

    if(windowWidth < 1000){
        videoHeight = windowHeight;
        videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
        $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'});

        $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight);
    }

    $('.homepage-hero-module .video-container video').addClass('fadeIn animated');

});
}
```

(as an aside, I can't get the video play button to disappear when this is viewed on mobile devices - if anyone can chip in with that too, that would be great!)

Thanks!
Scott

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that this issue occurs only on mobile devices!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the background element on the .video-container class:

```
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}
```

Like this:

```
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Gets rid of the black bar and leaves that area transparent.

Another small thing to try:

You could wrap your video inside a different div to give something else that defines the videos height rather than just the hard coded 400px height that will stay as a 400px strip of video on any sized screen.

```
<div id="homepage-wrapper">
  <div class="homepage-hero-module">
...
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#homepage-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Wrapping the whole video section would make it easier to manage the content in their that your video container inherits.

You can see the edits I made here: https://jsfiddle.net/kgill/napfds5o/3/

Comment: Thanks Kyle but unfortunately making the background transparent still leaves the gap - it's the gap I want to eliminate, not the blackness.  If you view the website (scott.ewarena.com/blog) on your phone you'll see the problem.

Comment: Maybe try changing the width in the .video-container video.fillWidth {} to auto instead of 100%?

Comment: Nope :( I wonder if it's something within the HTML that I've just missed completely?